# Tableau Calculated Field to Display Specific Rows

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I'm trying to find a way to display only certain rows of my data based off a very specific criteria. I will try to explain it the best way I can. Let's start with a screenshot here:

[Picture of part of the Tableau sheet as-is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMPv2.png)

What I'm trying to do is create a way to display only the values of "Order: Sales Order #" that have a value filled in for "Item: Connected Product Category". As you see on the screenshot, order number 15589543 has one Connected Product Category that displays "Connectable".
Since this order number does not only have null field for the Connect Product Category, I would like ALL of the rows (even the blank ones) be displayed for order # 15589543. If an order # has NO rows that have "connectable" displayed in them (orders 10305573, 15573299, 15699578, etc.) I would like these orders to be filtered out.

This is a screenshot of just a small part of the data. Basically, if an order has a "connectable" field in it, I need all of the rows for that order # to be displayed.

I tried to do logic such as `IF [Item: Connected Product Category] = "Connectable" THEN [Order: Sales Order #] ELSE NULL END` but this only displays the rows that literally contain "connectable" in them, not all of the rows for that order number.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. After extensive research I'm not sure if this is even possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.  Create a calculated field `desired filter` as

```
{FIXED [Order: Sales Order #] : SUM(
IF [Item: Connected Product Category] = 'Connectable' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
)} > 0
```

This calculated field will evalaute as TRUE/FALSE and setting filter on this field for `TRUE` will filter records as desired.

Try this.  Good luck